# capture the last WM_SIZE

Tags: c++, winapi, resize

When I resize my window I want to tell another part of my program that my window has changed size. I read on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646(VS.85).aspx) that:

*WM SIZE Message

The WM SIZE message is sent to a window after its size has changed.*

However, I receive the WM_SIZE even when dragging.
I noticed that there is also a WM_SIZING message that is sent when my window is resizing. At the moment I do not see the difference between WM_SIZE and WM_SIZING.

Is there some way I can capture the very last WM_SIZE message, as to not "spam" my program with resize messages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you start dragging a window, the system enters a modal move/resize loop; it does not return to your own message loop until the drag action has finished. You are still getting `WM_SIZE` because it is sent directly to the window procedure, but it does not flow through your own message loop.

At the beginning of such a modal drag action, the system sends [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632622(v=VS.85).aspx) to your window procedure. When you release the mouse button, your application will get [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632623%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). That is probably the message you want to trigger on.

Comment: Say if I am resizing a lot and I need to capture all these sizes. Which message do I use?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this pattern:

1. `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`
2. Zero or more groups of:

   1. `WM_SIZING`
   2. `WM_SIZE`
3. `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`

`WM_SIZING` doc says:

> lParam
>
> A pointer to a RECT structure with the screen coordinates of the drag
> rectangle. To change the size or position of the drag rectangle, an
> application must change the members of this structure.

Credit to this blog post: https://billthefarmer.github.io/blog/post/handling-resizing-in-windows/

> I have a windows app where I want the app window to maintain it’s
> aspect ratio when it is resized. Windows provides two mechanisms for
> this, the WM_SIZE message and the WM_SIZING message. The WM_SIZE
> message is sent when a window has been resized to allow child windows
> to be resized, the WM_SIZING message is sent while the user is
> resizing it to allow the size to be adjusted. The messages are handled
> in the WindowProc callback function.

Also, `WM_SIZING` provides:

> wParam
>
> The edge of the window that is being sized.

Ideas about capturing the last `WM_SIZE` message:

1. On each `WM_SIZE`, save whatever details you need into a global variable (or user data pointer associated with window handle).  On `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`, use last `WM_SIZE` details from global var.
2. On `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`, call `GetWindowRect()` or `GetClientRect()` depending upon your needs.

I am sure #1 will work, but I did not test #2.