# Resizing Dialog Box In MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to know is there any way or message in **MFC** by which one can know that a user has finished resizing the dilog box ..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override your window class' [OnSize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h464d4f3%28VS.80%29.aspx) function.

Comment: But this function is always being called when user is in the process of resizing the dialog box not when the user has finised the resizing..
I am looking for a message that should be fired,when the user is releasing the mouse left Btn after dragging the mouse with left button pressed for resizing ..

I tried WM_NCLBUTTONUP but it is very irregular does not fire always..

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797468/capture-the-last-wm-size. So you could just save the last `OnSize()` parameters, then when you receive `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` call a resize function that resizes your window based on the last `cx` and `cy` received by `OnSize()`.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the message WM_SIZE